# How to access a service in class library in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have 2 projects "Mvc.net Web application" and "C# Class Library" in my project solution, in web I am using autofac for accessing the services from "Class Library" using DI and its working fine.

When I tried accessing the service in my Class Library using the below line of code

```
var _emailSender = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IEmailSender>();
```

it throws the following error message

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext is not available.'

Any inputs to fix this would be really helpful.

Thanks,
Ramkumar K

Comment: Stepping back, I think you have a design flaw if you need to access the service from the library. I encourage you to refactor so that the dependency is one-way.

Comment: Actually the Service class is existing in the "Class Library" project itself but it does not have default parameter less constructor.